# WPF The type or namespace name 'CompositionInitializer' does not exist in the namespace 'System.ComponentModel.Composition'

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, namespaces

i am trying to convert my silverlight application to a wpf application. I have this piece of code which was written in silverlight where it has a reference to system.componentModel.Composition.CompositionInitializer but when i try to reference the same in WPF. It is not available. What should i do:

This is my error:

```
public ParserFactory()
    {
        System.ComponentModel.Composition.CompositionInitializer.SatisfyImports(this);

        foreach (var item in _ParserList)
        {
            var type = item.Metadata.ParserType;
            var value = item.Value;

            Parsers.Add(type, value);
        }
    }
```

This is my piece of code:

> Error 2   The type or namespace name 'CompositionInitializer' does not exist in the namespace 'System.ComponentModel.Composition' (are you missing an assembly reference?)    c:\Users\sahluwai\Desktop\cusControls2\leitch\HarrisSilverlightToolkit\Toolkit\Source\XmlSerializableObject\SerializerFactory.cs    44  47  XmlSerializableObject

What should i do. Is there some other assembly which i can reference. What is the workaround in WPF.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you referenced the assembly in your project?

Comment: "System.ComponentModel.Composition.CompositionInitializer" is not available in the list, When i try to add assemblies by right clicking on references and clicking on "Add Reference..."

Comment: any other ideas .what to do guys?

Comment: Add reference to `System.ComponentModel.Composition`. CompositionInitializer is a member in that assembly namespace

Comment: already tried that. it does not work. it is not  a part of System.ComponentModel.Composition

Comment: Please have a look at : http://reedcopsey.com/2010/03/26/mef-compositioninitializer-for-wpf/ hope can help

Answer (score 0):

You need a reference to the library System.ComponentModel.Composition.Initialization.dll to get access to that class.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.compositioninitializer(v=vs.95).aspx